# Why doesn't push move results from DB query into variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, express

**Intent**

Establishing a connection with a DB in my route, running a query, capturing the result, and making it accessible to my index view to render in the DOM.

**Problem**

DB connects and returns results successfully in the console. However, fails to push this result into the "finalResult" array.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

// Establish Connection with Database
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'xxxxxxx',
    database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

// // Query and post result to console
connection.query('SELECT * FROM products', function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    doSomething(results[0]);
});

connection.end();


var finalResult = ['hello'];

function doSomething(results) {
    console.log(results.name);
    finalResult.push(results.name);
}

console.log(finalResult);


// Render/make accessible to views
res.render('index', {
    pageTitle: 'Home',
    result: finalResult
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

`doSomething(results[0]);` successfully pushes the result into the `doSomething()` function because `console.log(results.name)` returns the correct query result. Issue occurs with `finalResult.push(results.name)` because `console.log(finalResult)` only returns an array with "hello" when it should have "hello" plus the query result.

Answer (score 1):

Please note when you query database from mysql module is synchronous (the query takes function as argument -- callback). That's mean you cannot take result value as variable outside the query function. Try to use async/await or promise to get returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write console.log(finalResult) inside doSomething function, after you pushed the new data to finalResult array.

I think that you see only "helo"  because console.log(finalResult) execute before the doSomething  function finished (before you add the data to finalResult array).

Comment: Yup, that does work. Though I'm still confused.. how can I get it to execute doSomething() first? I want to be able to pass the results into the res.render function.

Comment: You can move the res.render..... to the connection.query function, right after the calling to doSomething function or add a function for the res.rende and call this function right after  doSomething function.